# Quantized value of spin angular momentum and underlying mysteries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, quantum-spin, spinors

I think the quantized value of the spin angular momentum is $\hbar/2 $ rather than $\hbar $ is the basic reason for the $4\pi$ rotation of a wave function to retain its initial state again? Is it true?

So my question is from where we concluded the quantized value of spin angular momentum is  $\hbar/2 $. Is it an experimental proof? Does any theoretical proof exists for such a fact?

Comment: See e.g. the [Stern-Gerlanch experinent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment). the [Einstein-de Haas experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect).

Comment: The entire body of physics that involves electrons confirms experimentally that these have spin 1/2 in units of $\hbar$.

Comment: Where is the mystery?  You are confusing the convenience of defining $\hbar=h/2\pi$ with any possible range of rotation angles.  The $2\pi$ in the denominator has *nothing* to do with rotations.

Comment: i dont know to write h cross in mathematical notation using codes so I just write it as $h/2\pi$, my question is from where we get the quantized  value of spin angular momentum as $ h cross / 2$ @ ZeroTheHero

Comment: You write it as \hbar.

Comment: Thanks, @G. Smith

Comment: Waiting for all of your valuable responses

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest model the value of the magnetic moment $\mu$ of a charged particle (like the electron) is related to its orbital angular momentum $\vec L$ by
$$
\vec \mu=\frac{q}{2mc}\vec L\, .
$$
When a collection of atoms - say hydrogen atoms - are placed in a magnetic field 
$\vec B$, one can easily calculate using perturbation theory that the various quantum states of these atoms, which have the same energy when $\vec B=0$, actually separate in energy, and the separation $\Delta E$ between adjacent levels is proportional to $\hbar$ since the quantum angular momentum $L_z$ has eigenvalues $\hbar m_z$.

Thus, the $\ell=0$ state would not split but the $\ell=1$ states should split in three states close in energy if $\vec B$ is "small''.

It turns out that state $\ell=0$ splits in $2$ magnetic substates, while the $\ell=1$ states splits in $6$.  The energy difference $\Delta E$ is still proportional to $\hbar$ but since there are two states this implies that the state higher in energy has *spin* eigenvalue $+\hbar/2$ while the lower state has eigenvalue $-\hbar/2$ so that $\Delta E=\hbar$.

Note that this splitting of states in a weak magnetic field was one of the experimental evidence that lead to the downfall of the Bohr model, since the Bohr model did not adequately predict this splitting: the lowest energy state in the Bohr model has $\ell=+1\hbar$ so should split 3 ways whereas it splits only $2$ ways experimentally.  In the Schrodinger model the state should not split.  Once we include spin, Bohr's ground state should split $6$ ways and Schrodinger $2$ ways; this last is in accordance with experiment.

Finally, the Stern-Gerlach experiment also "measures" spin by passing atoms in a magnetic field gradient, where they experience a force proportional to $\vec \mu$ and thus proportional to either $\vec L$ or $\vec S$.  They observed the beam split two ways, incompatible with any integer value of $\ell$ but compatible with $s=1/2$ so that again $m_z=\pm \hbar/2$.  Phipps and Taylor redid this with a beam of hydrogen with atoms in the ground state, to remove any possible ambiguity on the angular momentum value in the ground state of silver atoms.

Answer (score 1):

Let's summarize. The first evidence for value 1/2 of electron spin -
or better, for the very fact that electrons do have a nonzero
intrinsic angular momentum - came from doublet structure of levels of
alkaline metals (Li, Na, K, ...).

The level splitting suggested a spin angular momentum, which combined
with orbital momentum gave rise to multiple values ($l-s \ldots l+s$)
for total angular momentum $j$.

The appearance of only two levels for a given $l$ said that $s=1/2$, so
that $j$ could only be $l+1/2$ or $l-1/2$.

Stern-Gerlach experiment directly proved that Ag atoms in ground state
have a magnetic moment (only due to electron spin) capable of only two
values for component in direction of magnetic field. Since magnetic
moment is proportional to angular momentum, the same had to hold for the
latter. As angular momentum components can only vary in steps spaced
by $\hbar$, you get two values only if $s=1/2\,\hbar$ ($s_z=+1/2\,\hbar, 
-1/2\,\hbar$).

To conclude, it's not correct to write

> the $4\pi$ rotation of a wave function to retain its initial state
>   again

I mean that a distinction must be made between *wave function* and
*state*. You know that two wave functions differing only by a
constant factor represent the same state. What happens with 1/2
particles is that a $2\pi$ rotation changes sign of wave function. Then
the state is unchanged, whereas the wave function has changed. A further
$2\pi$ rotation reproduces initial wave function and of course
initial state too.